# How can i convert decimeters to tons per capita?

Tags: converters

I don't know how to convert from decimeters to ton per capita?

I have tried to convert it to kilograms by multiplying with 1000? I read that 1 ton is 1000 kilograms so I did like that but not sure where to go from there?

For example how do I go from 0,00069 decimeters to ton per capita?

Comment: Carbon tax math, folks.

Comment: Hey @soke13 what tool or programming language are going to use for that?

Comment: This is not about programming.

Comment: And besides, how does "decimeters" even relate to "tons per capita"? Those measure diferent things.

Comment: I used stata comando "reg" and combined different regressions and got a table and its CO2 emissions per capita and the numbers from the table is in decimeters

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this cubic decimeters to tons (displacement) conversion formula:

```
Volume(DT) = Volume (dm³) × 0.0010089904777568
```

1 cubic decimeter is equal to `0.0010089904777568` tons.

For example, you need to convert 500 cubic decimeters to tons (displacement):

```
Volume(DT) = 500dm³ × 0.0010089904777568 (DT/dm³)
Volume(DT) = 0.5044952388784 DT
```

Comment: I use stata command "reg" with 5 different regressions and combined it to a table and got different regressions